# FHIR resource that supports concept no known allergy

Tags: rest, semantic-web, hl7, hl7-fhir

Is there a 'no known allergy' mechanism defined in HL7 FHIR resources somewhere in the specification?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"No known Allergy" would be conveyed using the [List](http://hl7.org/fhir/list.htm) resource.

I.e. You'd have a List for the patient's allergies/intolerances (or perhaps one specific to drug allergies or something).  List allows you to say "none known" or something similar in the List.emptyReason element.

Answer (score 1):

http://hl7.org/fhir/us/core/stu1/StructureDefinition-us-core-allergyintolerance.html

Guidance says as below. This is correct approach now in this era. This is for everyone coming here looking for an answer to this dated question :)

Profile specific implementation guidance:

No Known Allergies may be represented using the US Core-AllergyIntolerance profile with appropriate negation code in AllergyIntolerence.code.

I have listed codes that can be used below from  codeset- http://hl7.org/fhir/us/core/ValueSet/us-core-substance-sct

Code    Display Definition
409137002   No known drug allergy (situation)
428197003   No known insect allergy (situation)
428607008   No known environmental allergy (situation)
429625007   No known food allergy (situation)
716184000   No known latex allergy (situation)
716220001   No known animal allergy (situation)